# cvs update: Case ambiguity between xxx\yyy and (null). Using (null)

Tags: cvs

I started seeing this error message when doing a `cvs update` on Windows systems.  What is its cause?

Strangely, neither stackoverflow, nor google seemed to know the answer at the moment.  So, I will supply the cause here for the next unfortunate victim of this sabotage...

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that someone had committed a file to the CVS repository with a backslash in its name on a Unix-like system (Cygwin, in this case).  The commit was purely accidental, so I could simply remove the file to resolve the issue:

```
$ rm "xxx\yyy"
$ cvs rm "xxx\yyy"
$ cvs ci -m"Removing accidental commit." "xxx\yyy"
```